# rvm and gem install issue

Tags: rubygems, rvm

When I try to install gems with RVM I get this error:

```
gem install rake 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - /Users/paladiy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p399/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem
```

And also when I call `gem list` I get an empty list.

How can I install gems in this situation?

Comment: You should accept the answer below if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

mkdir ~/.rvm/gems/cache

Comment: Oh! I didn't think it was so easy. Thanks Michael.